# Creating an array of IDs and randomize their age

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I have to generate 160k of IDs in a text file and have to randomize their age.
I have generated the IDs using an array but I don't know how to randomize their age into the text file.

There is also a criteria to randomize the age :

- 10% from 160000 IDs are 60-90 years old,
- 30% for 25-60
- 25% for 13-24
- 35% for 1-12

here are the code for my random ID generate :

```
public class Citizenid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try{
             try (PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("citizen id.txt")) {

                    int totalAgesToGenerate = 160000;
                    int ages60To90 = (int) (totalAgesToGenerate * 0.1);
                    int ages25To59 = (int) (totalAgesToGenerate * 0.3);
                    int ages13To24 = (int) (totalAgesToGenerate * 0.25);
                    int ages1To12 = (int) (totalAgesToGenerate * 0.35);

                    Random r = new Random();
                    int age;
                    int index=0;
                    int []agearray;
                    agearray = new int[160000];

                    //generating age for 60-90 age group
                    for (int i = 0; i < ages60To90; i++) {
                        age = r.nextInt(31) + 60; 
                        agearray[index]=age;
                        index++;
                    }
                    //generating age for 25-59 age group
                    for (int i = 0; i < ages25To59; i++) {
                        age = r.nextInt(35) + 25; 
                        agearray[index]=age;
                        index++;
                    }
                    //generating age for 13-24 age group
                    for (int i = 0; i < ages13To24; i++) {
                        age = r.nextInt(12) + 13; 
                        agearray[index]=age;
                        index++;
                    }
                     //generating age for 1-12 age group
                    for (int i = 0; i < ages1To12; i++) {
                        age = r.nextInt(12) + 1; 
                        agearray[index]=age;
                        index++;
                    }  

                 int a=1;
                 int[]arrayid = new int[160000];
                 for(int i=0;i<arrayid.length;i++){
                     p.printf("%06d , %d \n",a,agearray[r.nextInt(1600001)]);
                     a++;
                 }
                 p.close();
             }
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

             System.out.println("No such file exist");
        }  
    }
}
```

I have solved the age problem but I wonder why the output is "No such file exist". It doesn't write on the textile

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayid.length;i++){
    p.printf("%06d %2d\n",a, getRandomAge());
    a++;
}
// ------ outside main function ------
private static Random random = new Random();

private static int getRandomAge() {
    int groupId = random.nextInt(100);
    if (groupId < 10) {
        return 60 + random.nextInt(30); // 10% age 60-90
    } else if (groupId < 40) {
        return 25 + random.nextInt(35); // 30% age 25-60
    } else if (groupId < 65) {
        return 13 + random.nextInt(11); // 25% age 13-24
    }
    return 1 + random.nextInt(12); // the rest 35% age 1-13
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `Random` class will do it for you. It has the `nextInt(n)` method, than generates a random number between 0 and n-1.

So if you want ages between 60 and 90 you would write something like this:

```
Random generator = new Random();
int age = generator.nextInt(31) + 60;
```

It will generate a random integer between 0 and 30, and you just add 60 to obtain a range [60, 90].

Plus, if you have to generate ages with percentages, the only thing you have to do is make some loops.

```
int totalAgesToGenerate = 160000;
int ages60To90 = totalAgesToGenerate * 0.1;
int ages13To24 = totalAgesToGenerate * 0.25;
int ages25To59 = totalAgesToGenerate * 0.3;
int ages1To12 = totalAgesToGenerate - ages60to90 - ages13To14 - ages25To59;
Random generator = new Random();
int age;
int destinationIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ages60To90; i++) {
    age = generator.nextInt(31) + 60;
    ageid[destinationIndex] = age;
    destinationIndex++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < ages13To24; i++) {
    age = generator.nextInt(12) + 13;
    ageid[destinationIndex] = age;
    destinationIndex++;
}
```

And so on.

The generation and saving can also be done in other ways. It's just an example.

Comment: do I have to put it in another class?

Comment: There's no need. You can add that code just where you generate IDs, and adapt it to your actual program. But you can if you want.

Comment: do I have to put 4 different loops for each age group to store in the array?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I would do it that way. If you do so, you'll need an index variable shared across all the loops to make one generated age be stored inside one cell in your array.

Comment: You're welcome! Plus, I recommend you to make the [tour] of the website and mark the answer that solves your problem as accepted.

Comment: I've edited the code but the output shows "No such file exist". It doesn't write on the textile.

Comment: That only means that a file named `citizen id.txt` does not exist. It has nothing to do with the loops and the random generator. You should verify that such file exists before writing on it. And if it doesn't, you have to create the file. I recommend you the `File` class for that.

Comment: Maybe you could ask that in a new question. But the main reasons aren't that many. It could be that you're not in the right directory, or that the program has no permissions to write into the file.

Comment: try with file name that doesn't contain spaces

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Math.random()` as follow `(Math.random() * (max_value - min_value)) + min_value)`

```
int size = 160000;
int[]ageid=new int[size];
for(int i=0;i<ageid.length;i++){
    if(i<(size*0.1))// 10% 
       ageid[i]=(Math.random() * (90- 60)) + 60); //age 60-90
    else if(i<(size*0.4))  // 30% 
       ageid[i]=(Math.random() * (60- 25)) + 25);//age 25-60
    else if(i<(size*0.65))// 25% 
       ageid[i]=(Math.random() * (24- 13)) + 13);//age 13-24
    else // the rest which is 35% 
       ageid[i]=(Math.random() * (12- 1) + 1);//age 1-12
}
```